# Node and Sequelize: user model structure

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I create a simple API, that allows user verification. In theory, everything works, but I have a few questions about the user signing.

Currently in my model I have a funcions *findUser* and *loginUser*. So in the controller this look like that:

```
let loginUser = (req, res, next) => {
  let data = {
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  }
  db.Users.findUser(data.username)
  .then((result) => {
    return db.Users.loginUser(result.user, data)
  }).then((result) => res.json(result))
  .catch((err) => next(err))
}
```

It works, but the function *loginUser* needs to get the whole object returned by Sequelize from *findUser*. On the other hand, in order to use *findUser* in another place, I don't need everything informations about user (e.g. password).

So what is the better option? Something similar to my current solution (I don't know, maybe second find function?) or use sequelize find method in my *loginUser* function?